# How to fix mono using 100% CPU?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, cpu-usage, suse

I've got a problem where I'm running a background process using mono 3.0.3 on a SLES box, and while using top I discovered that it's using 100% CPU. I searched and have tried the following possible solutions:

1) Setting the MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU environment variable to 1000, i.e.

`export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=1000`

This did not work. I tried with 300, per [this thread](http://opensimulator.org/mantis/view.php?id=3353), but that did not work, either.

2) According to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337884/program-with-system-timers-timer-runned-via-mono-project-causes-high-cpu-load), using Timers in the program to be executed using mono might cause high CPU load, however I made a very simple test program with just an infinite loop and ran it... and mono still had 100% CPU usage.

This is the program I used to test whether it was simply due to using Timers:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Stayin alive.");
        }
    }
```

3) I thought perhaps this was an issue in mono 3.0.3, so I upgraded to 3.6.0, which is apparently the latest version recommended for SLES 11.3. Mono still takes up 99-100% CPU.

So I'm left wondering what is going on and how can I fix this issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your test code would run 100% CPU usage on any system (mono/.NET/c++/etc), its an infinite loop with no yield... I'm guessing the issue is in your code, not in Mono's setup. Without seeing what you are doing, its hard to tell you how to fix it but I'm guessing this isn't the right path. Just because the thread is background doesn't mean it can't be a processor resource hog.

Comment: Did you try running the code in the question you linked? That would be a better way to see if timers are an issue. Like already said infinite loops will always be 100% if you don't sleep somewhere.

Comment: "how can I fix this issue"  Don't use silly infinite while loops that don't actually do anything.  You can manually "throttle" the loop back by calling `Thread.Sleep()` with a small interval in there within your loop.  On a side note, a single core system would be at 100%.  A dual core system would see 50%, while a 3 core system would see 33% usage, etc...get the idea?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is a blocking call, it would still be using 100% of the resources available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting CPU would need to be set at the linux level. For example:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage

example

```
cpulimit -l 50 COMMAND
```

Otherwise, there is likely a bug in the code causing this that needs to be fixed (e.g. infinite loops).

Comment: Indeed, it was an infinite loop (a one liner at that).